# Prevent duplicated data when paginated through records that has the same value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pagination

I have a MySQL database for example,

| ID | Title | Purchase_At |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Title A | 2023-12-01 |
| 2 | Title B | 2023-08-22 |
| 3 | Title C | 2023-12-01 |
| 4 | Title D | 2023-08-23 |
| 5 | Title E | 2023-12-01 |
| 6 | Title F | 2023-06-22 |
| 7 | Title G | 2023-12-01 |
| 8 | Title H | 2023-08-02 |

I'm building infinite loading in both direction.

Say my initial retrieval is `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Purchase_At DESC LIMIT 3` and it returns ID 1, 3 and 5.

If i want to load anything before ID 1, I do `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Purchase_At < '2023-12-01' ORDER BY Purchase_At DESC LIMIT 3`?

And vise versa, loading anything after 5, I do `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Purchase_At > '2023-12-01' ORDER BY Purchase_At  DESC LIMIT 3`?

As you can see, there are chance that i might encounter repeated data since the ordering on multiple records with same value isn't reliable. I can't do `WHERE ID < 1` or `WHERE ID > 5` either.

I can't use paignation query like `LIMIT` or `OFFSET` either because during user viewing, new records will be added and that'll mess up the pagination.

Purchase_At is something user entered via a datepicker for receipt date and that's it, there is no millisecond etc... Year, Month and Day is all I got. In my case, there could be user with 10 receipts in same day. If I were to paginate it 3 per page, how can i make sure my infinite loading doesn't produce repeated data?

---

To make my question easier to understand, think as of a fb chat system. Where user scroll down to load new messages and scroll up to load old messages. How can i achieve that same by only knowing my sort can have multiple same Purchase_At value with just year, month and day.

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you're using (Postgres, SQL Server, whatever) as there may be vendor-specific solutions to your problem.

Comment: thanks, information added, i'm using MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem: your "Purchase_At" date column is not unique, so it is not usable as an index to seek into the results, and ordering by date is not guaranteed to return rows in the same order every time.

Solution: use (Purchase_At,id) instead. This is unique and it will have a stable order.

[DB Fiddle example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jvizNyvKGZZn2BWR93HX9E/0).

```
create table foo (d date, id integer auto_increment primary key );
insert into foo (d) values ('2000-01-01'),('2000-01-02'),('2000-01-03'),('2000-01-01'),('2000-01-02'),('2000-01-03');
```

Get the first 3 rows:

```
select * from foo order by d,id limit 3;
```

The last row from the previous query has (d,id)=('2000-01-02',2) so in order to get the next row, simply use ">":

```
select * from foo where (d,id) > ('2000-01-02',2) order by d,id limit 3;
```

A multicolumn index on (d,id) would optimize this query and avoid a sort.

Comment: Oh wow, i didn't know you can do where clause like that. thanks.